# querystring with backbone marionette router

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to output the query string but I'm not getting anything but null.

My query string is `http:://localhost/admin/brands?foo=bar` and `queryString` is always null also tried `/brands/?foo=bar` but no luck

```
App.Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    routes: {
        '(?*queryString)': 'index',
        'create': 'create',
        'edit/:id': 'edit',
        'show/:id': 'show',
    },      
    index: function(queryString) {

        console.log('index page');

        //let qs = helper.parseQueryString(queryString);
        console.log(queryString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to enable push state like `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})` or your URL should contain `#` like `http:://localhost/admin/brands#?foo=bar`